# Pandas Where Method: How to query if a value is in a list that is a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the DataFrame below:

```
           a
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [5, 6, 7]
```

I am trying to find the rows where 1 is contained by the value of column b (a list). So for the table above the query would return:

```
           a
0  [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried:

```
> df.where(1 in df.a)
ValueError: where requires an ndarray like object for its condition
```

and:

```
> df.query('1 in a')
KeyError: True
```

Could someone please let me know if there is a way to do this with either the where or query methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways, but a simple method is to access the list with `apply` and a `lambda` function:

```
df[df.a.apply(lambda seq: 1 in seq)]
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a way to do this while using either the where or query methods of pandas.

Comment: Ex: df.query('b = 1 & 1 in a')